# WordPress rest API get Posts parent by post ID

Tags: posts, rest-api

I have this url  `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`
. it gets me all the posts I want, but what I need is the Parent ID of the Post. Is there an endpoint for example `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/parent/{postID}` ??

Comment: Hey! As far as I know, posts can’t have parents, but pages can. So the [page endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/) also provides you with the parent ID, but the post endpoint doesn’t. Does that help or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: I think it helps, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As [posts can’t have parents](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36300/can-posts-have-parents), there is no endpoint to get the parent ID of a post.

However, pages can have parents, so the [page endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/) should return a parent ID, among other things. So, by getting `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages`, you should be able to get the `parent` attribute, which is “The ID for the parent of the object.” If you want just the parent, you could use `_filter` in your request.